# How can we optimize the adding of multiple parameters to make the feature file generic to run sql query in latest cypress version?

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am using the below feature file to perform the `sql query` run using `cy.task()` in latest Cypress version. This is working fine, but is there any other clear way to perform sql query to include more parameters and to make a generic feature file line/ step definition ? Can someone please advise ?

```
Cypress: 10.3.0
Cypress-Cucumber-Preprocsessor
```

//Feature file line:

```
Scenario: Run the sql query to verify the user details in the User table
    Given I run the sql query to get "FirstName, LastName, Email, Address" for the user email "sam@test.com"
```

// databaseQuery.cy.js

```
Then('I run the sql query to get {string} for the user email {string}', (query, userEmail) => {
    cy.task('queryDb', `SELECT ${query} FROM Users WHERE Email="${userEmail}"`).then((result) => {
        expect(result[0].FirstName).to.equal("Sam");
        expect(result[0].LastName).to.equal("Thinker");
        expect(result[0].Email).to.equal(userEmail);
        expect(result[0].Address).to.equal("455 Sydney Street");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of is to have an object of properties and values you would want to validate the response against and then use the properties from this same object in your query.

Let's assume you have an object as below.

```js
    const user = {
      FirstName: "Sam",
      LastName: "Thinker",
      Email: "sam@test.com",
      Address: "455 Sydney Street"
    }
```

Then your code can be altered as something like below:

```
Scenario: Run the sql query to verify the user details in the User table
   Given I run the sql query to get "userdetails" for the user email "sam@test.com"
```

```js
Then(
  'I run the sql query to get {string} for the user email {string}',
  (query, userEmail) => {
    const queryParams =
      query == 'userdetails' ? Object.keys(user).join(', ') : '*';
    cy.task(
      'queryDb',
      `SELECT ${queryParams} FROM Users WHERE Email="${userEmail}"`
    ).then((result) => {
      expect(result[0]).to.deep.equal(user);
    });
  }
);
```

This would also mean the query params are hidden from the cucumber feature file.

Comment: We need to add the `user` obj in the step definition file right  ?

Comment: Yes. that's right. Or you can place it in a different location and import it into the test file.

Comment: Ok, will try that and let you know the outcome

Comment: Getting some error in this line `const queryParams = query == 'userdetails'? Object.keys(user).join(', ') : *`

Comment: I could see some problem with else condition in ternary ops ..and getting error `Cannot access 'queryParams' before initialization`

Comment: could you add quotes around the `*` ? 

`const queryParams = query == 'userdetails'? Object.keys(user).join(', ') : '*'`

Comment: Thank you, that is working now,  can we add  null in the else condition ?

Comment: I guess yes but that will anyway fail your expect statement.